# My properties panel is horizontal, how do I turn it back to vertical?

Tags: interface, properties

I'm not entirely sure what happened, maybe a hit the wrong key. ut my properties bar is horizontal, it's playing hell with my ability to select anything that takes up a lot of vertical room (like modifiers).

[image]

How would I go about correcting this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rightclick in the panel, and pick Vertical

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was disgustingly simple. Thank you.

Comment: @douglasg14b i'm surprised it hasn't been asked before, not that I could find anyway